# Current employer not exporting to CSV

Tags: export, fields, csv

I have tagged a group of contacts and am exporting them to a CSV file. When I do this, of the 30 contacts only about 25 show the current employer in the CSV file. I checked the remaining five and they have a current employer listed in the contact record, but it does not export. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you try after resaving the contact and exporting those 5 contacts?

Comment: Hi Pradeep, That worked. I don't understand why it was not picking up their current employer even though this was listed in the record to begin with. Each of these contacts had duplicate emails listed. There was one email listed as work and one (the same email address listed as home). I am concerned that this might happen with a list where there are more than five contacts who employer does not export. I don't want to go in and resave a lot of contacts. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

CiviCRM populates current employer based on what is stored in civicrm_contact.current_employer rather employee/employer of relationship. While adding employee/employer of relationship relationship the form provide is_current employee option, if ticked  civicrm_contact.current_employer is stored with organization name and also same field is used in add/edit contact form.

For some reason the data for 5 contacts didn't had civicrm_contact.current_employer saved properly, resaving them might populated the field correctly.

Comment: Thank you Pradeep. I really appreciate your help. I will examine your answer in more detail later today. I will get back to you if I have any more questions. You have been very helpful.